# Optimizing debugging speed of Java Web app working with Spring and Jetty?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, jetty

I use Spring Framework 3.x, jetty-8.1.10.v20130312, IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4, Maven.
I've noticed that since some time I have to wait too much time when I want to debug Java code for web app. 
If I run app without debug in IDEA, then it' OK.

In debug:

`2013-08-27 16:02:08.107:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.10.v20130312`

`2013-08-27 16:02:09.706:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.`

`2013-08-27 16:02:16.157:INFO:/:No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath`

`2013-08-27 16:02:16.600:INFO:/:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext`

`2013-08-27 16:05:23.671:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started`

`SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9110`

`[INFO] Started Jetty Server`

Run without debug:

`2013-08-27 16:17:22.651:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.10.v20130312`

`2013-08-27 16:17:24.286:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.`

`2013-08-27 16:17:30.368:INFO:/:No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath`

`2013-08-27 16:17:30.788:INFO:/:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext`

`2013-08-27 16:17:40.317:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9110`

`[INFO] Started Jetty Server`

How can I fix slow performance?

Comment: Remove method breakpoints, see http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bro! I've updated JDK from 1.7.0_3 to 1.7.0_25. Now debugging is faster.
Other colleagues also noticed that JDK reinstallation (or JDK update, I don't know exactly) helps.